# Como limitar caracteres num textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Como limitar a quantidade de caracteres em um `Textbox` em `xaml` e via `code behind`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É bem simples:

em `Xaml` adicione:

```
MaxLength="500"
```

e no código c#:

```
NomeDoTextBox.MaxLength = 500;
```

Se você tiver muitos textbox pode criar uma váriavél com esse valor:

```
public const int TamMaxCaracteres = 500;

NomeDoTextBox.MaxLength = TamMaxCaracteres;
```